# Headless Selenium test which fills out a form?

Tags: java, selenium, selenium-webdriver, headless-browser

We have a terminal application which serves webcontent via iFrames to our clients.

For some reason, it has been decided that we want to automate the test for this server side. I need to visit a page, fill out a form, and submit it - without actually rendering it in a GUI, I believe a headless selenium driver can do this - but I am new to selenium, does anyone have an example of how to do this in java with selenium?

Comment: SO is for specific coding questions. You are asking for references that you could/should look up yourself or someone to write the code for you. Do some googling, write some code, and if it doesn't do what you want, come back and ask the question with your specific problem.

Comment: Found the ruby developer.

Answer (score 2):

You can use PhantomJS. [Here](https://github.com/bonigarcia/webdrivermanager-examples/blob/master/src/test/java/io/github/bonigarcia/wdm/test/PhatomJsTest.java) you can find a working example.

Comment: This is exactly what I was looking for - Was having trouble googling what I wanted because I knew I needed some other tool - thanks!